# ActionLink<> generic version not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a bit fed up with these Html helpers.

I did a lot of research on the net but can't finf anything..

Am I the only guy on earth that can't get the Html.ActionLink working...

Here is what I am trying to get working :

```
<%=Html.ActionLink<CatalogController>(x=>x.Index(parent.Name,child.Name),child.Name) %>
```

I get the ActionLink method but can't get ActionLink< > generic method from intellisense.

I have added Microsoft.Web.Mvc reference to my project and here is my pages section of my Web config file :

```
<namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
            <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
            <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
            <add namespace="CoderForTraders.Data"/>
            <add namespace="CoderForTraders.Web.Controllers"/>

            <add namespace="AspNetMvcTypeSafety.Controllers"/>
            <add namespace="AspNetMvcTypeafety.Models"/>
            <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/>
        </namespaces>
```

What is going on !!

Thanks

Comment: Just a quick thought, have you imported Microsoft.Web.Mvc into the file you want to use this template method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think asp.net mvc assembly itself has Html.ActionLink **with the control** as its template , the template version you are using, it only has Html.ActionLink, you may need to find some other assembly to support that function.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add it to the  section of your web.config in the Views folder if one exists so that intellisence can pick it up (you may need to restart Visual Studio because intellisence may be cached)